# Next.js 13のApp Routerでサーバー側で最新の情報を用いてHTMLをレンダリングし、かつポーリングして表示更新する

Tags: next.js

teratailとのクロスポストです。
https://teratail.com/questions/m36tsrglghhmol

#### 実現したいこと

- ページ単位で状態を共有する（実装済みだが、Next.jsの枝葉をClient Componentにして幹はServer Componentにするという原則に反してしまっているので、できれば解消したい）。
- ブラウザでページロード時に即座に最新の情報が表示されるようにするため、サーバー側で最新の情報を用いてHTMLをレンダリングする（必ずしも必要な機能ではないが、技術的チャレンジとして）。
- APIをポーリングし、表示を更新する（実装済みだが、 `useEffect` を使うことでClient Componentになってしまう）。

#### 前提

Next.js 13のApp Routerを用いてWebアプリを開発していますが、上記の要件を満たす方法が分かりません。

#### 該当のソースコード

```
import { QueueItem } from './types';

export default class Manager {
  static current = new LiveStreamManager();

  #items: QueueItem[] = [];

  private constructor() {
    this.fetchItems();
    setInterval(() => this.fetchItems(), 600 * 1000); // 10mins
  }

  getItems(): QueueItem[] {
    return this.#items;
  }

  async fetchItems() {
    ...
  }
```

フロントエンドで再生するアイテムを管理するサーバー側のクラスです。

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

import Manager from "@/app/api/Manager";

export async function GET() {
  let manager = Manager.current;
  return NextResponse.json(manager.getItems());
}
```

APIです。

```
'use client';

import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import { QueueItem } from '@/app/api/types';

import Player from './components/Player';
import QueueList from './components/QueueList';

function App() {
  console.log('rendering App');

  const [items, setItems] = useState<QueueItem[]>([]);
  const [currentItemID, setCurrentItemID] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    refresh();
    let timer = setInterval(refresh, 10000);
    return () => { clearInterval(timer); };
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  async function refresh() {
    console.log('refresh');

    let items = await fetch(`/api/items`).then(res => res.json()) as QueueItem[];
    setItems(items);
    if (currentItemID === '' && items.length > 0) {
      setCurrentItemID(items[0].id);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="h-screen flex bg-slate-900 text-white text-sm">
      <Player
        className='grow h-full'
        videoID={currentItemID}
        onEnded={() => {
          ...
        }}
      />
      <QueueList
        items={items}
        currentQueueID={currentItemID}
        setQueueID={setCurrentItemID}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

フロントエンドです。Client Componentに指定しています。

#### 試したこと

以下のように書き換えてみました。

```
async function App() {
  console.log('rendering App');

  // const [items, setItems] = useState<QueueItem[]>([]);
  let items = await fetch(`/api/streams`, { next: { revalidate: 10 } }).then(res => res.json()) as QueueItem[];
  const [currentItemID, setCurrentItemID] = useState('');
  const videoID = items.find(item => item.id === currentItemID)?.media.videoID;

  return (
    ...
  );
}
```

サーバーにおいてレンダリングされているようですが、 `TypeError: Failed to parse URL from /api/streams` というエラーが出ます。また、ブラウザ側で再描画とネットワークリクエストが無限ループします。

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

```js
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "13.4.6",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

## 1. ページ単位で状態を共有する

`app/page.tsx` を単一のComponentを返すServer Componentとする。

```
async function Page() {
  return <App />;
}

export default Page;
```

## 2. ブラウザでページロード時に即座に最新の情報が表示されるようにするため、サーバー側で最新の情報を用いてHTMLをレンダリングする

`app/page.tsx` はServer Componentなので、サーバー側の関数が使える。

```
async function Page() {
  console.log('rendering Page');

  const streams = await getLiveStreamItems();
  const videos = await getVideoItems();

  return (
    <App
      initialStreams={streams}
    />
  );
}

export default Page;
```

## 3. APIをポーリングし、表示を更新する

[SWR](https://swr.vercel.app/ja)というライブラリを使う。

```
'use client';

import { useState } from 'react';
import useSWR from 'swr';
import type { SWRConfiguration } from 'swr';

import fetcher from '@/app/utils/fetcher';

import Player from './Player';
import List from './List';

type Props = {
  initialStreams: QueueItem[];
};

function App(props: Props) {
  const { initialStreams } = props;
  const [currentItemID, setCurrentItemID] = useState('');

  // https://swr.vercel.app/ja/docs/typescript#generics
  let config: SWRConfiguration = {
    refreshInterval: 60_000, // 1 minute
    fallbackData: initialStreams,
  };
  let { data: streams } = useSWR<QueueItem>('/api/streams', fetcher, config);
  streams = streams ?? [];

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="flex">
        <Player
          className='grow'
          videoID={videoID}
          onEnded={() => {...}}
        />
      </div>
      <List
        className='m-4 mx-auto'
        streamItems={streams}
        currentItemID={currentItemID}
        setItemID={setCurrentItemID}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```